# Python: Paramiko module hangs when trying to nest ssh connections

Tags: python, linux, networking, ssh, paramiko

**I did not want to make this too long as it would be tedious to read so if you dont want to read it i basically want to know how to run nested ssh and receive the output to a variable. Note: My script examples here are all experimental i changed them so much that they may be fully wrong.**

I am having a problem when writing a python script to complete the Bandit games located at [overthewire.com](http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit1.html).

I have succeeded in completing the first 12 levels however at level 13 the game requires you to use a private key and ssh from within the current level. Which means i need to have a nested ssh within the paramiko module. I have been using exec_command for most of the other levels, **However when entering any commands that has to do with network(e.g. Netcat,telnet,ssh,openssl connect, etc) The script hangs when using normal exec_command**

I have done some research and discovered the ssh.invoke_shell command which launches an invisable shell. This way seems to work however i need to grab the input which would return me the password for the next level. When grabbing input i am unsure how to receive the full amount of input as it only displays a certain amount of bytes `(channel.recv(9999))` and it is very inconsistent.

**How can i have nested SSH within paramiko. I am confused on what to loop through. This method uses ssh.invoke_shell()**

```
import paramiko

def connect(server,user,pwd):
try:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
    ssh.connect(server,username=user,password=pwd)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print "Invalid password!"
    sys.exit()    
except:
    print "Please check your internet connection!"
    sys.exit()

if re.search('^bandit[0-9]$|^bandit1[0-9]$|^bandit2[0-5]', UserInput):

   if UserInput == 'bandit13':
       pwd = '8ZjyCRiBWFYkneahHwxCv3wb2a1ORpYL'
       connect(server,user,pwd)
       chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
       data = ' '
       while True:
          if chan.recv_ready():
             resp = chan.recv(9999)
             data += resp

          else:
               continue

          if data.endswith("bandit13@melinda~$:"):
             chan.send("ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i sshkey.private bandit14@localhost\n") 
          if data.endswith("bandit14@melinda~$:"): 
             channel.send("cat /etc/bandit_pass/bandit14\n")
             data += chan.recv(9999)
             break
          else:
             break
       print data
    ssh.close()
```

Other code i would run would just to try and receive all the output would be really inconsistent for example:

```
   chan.send('''ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i sshkey.private bandit14@localhost''')
    data = ' '
    for c in range(1,50):
        if chan.recv_ready:
            resp = chan.recv(9999)
            data += resp
    print data
    ssh.close()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.18.1-x86_64-linode50 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Welcome to the OverTheWire games machine !

Please read /README.txt for more information on how to play the levels
on this gameserver.

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

@lodit13@melinda:~$ ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -i sshkey.private bandit14
```

**Which basically shows me that i am not printing the full output. This is very inconsistent as sometimes the script would just hang.**